# Exception while accessing FileInfo Class

Tags: c#, file-io, system.io.fileinfo

I am trying to access all the files inside sub folders which are present inside a master folder, along with their last access times.

I am able to get all the files, the problem arises when I'm trying to get the last access times.

I receive the '**Object not set to an instance of an object**' exception.

I am not able to see the  anomaly in my code.

Below is the code:

```
public List<String> GetDirs(string Dir)
        {
            List<String> files = new List<String>();
            try
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(Dir))
                {
                    files.Add(f);
                }
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(Dir))
                {
                    files.AddRange(GetDirs(d));
                }
                int num=files.Count;
                FileInfo[] fileinfo=null;
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                {
                    fileinfo[i] = new FileInfo(files[i]);//Exception at this line of code

                }
                foreach(FileInfo xx in fileinfo)
                {
                    Response.Write(xx.LastWriteTime);
                }
              }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Response.Write(excpt.Message);
            }

            return files;
        }
```

The code is called as:

```
    string fullPath = @"D:\Main\Folder1";
    List<string> lst=GetDirs(fullPath);
```

The code is not complete at this time.

There are 3 text files inside Folder1, such as:

**D:\Main\Folder1\a.txt**

**D:\Main\Folder1\bin\a1.txt**

**D:\Main\Folder1\SubFolder1\sa1.txt**

I am trying to get the last access times for the above files too, but the exception doesn't permit to go further.

Comment: Sorry, but you have the debugger, probably the entire Visual Studio support, and you don't know the exactly line of the exception?

Comment: Well which line is throwing the exception, and what have you done to diagnose it?

Comment: By inspection, `fileinfo[i]` is going to fail as `fileinfo` is null... How did you expect that to work?

Comment: @JonSkeet fileinfo[0]=new FileInfo(D:\Main\Folder1\a.txt)..I think on the first iteration, the above line of code should arrive..

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I have debugged and have pointed out the line of code which throws the exception. Have a look again to the question.

Comment: You must agree with me, that you could make things easier...

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I totally second your point. Next time onwards I will make the codes and comments pretty clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty obvious here:

```
FileInfo[] fileinfo=null;   // <-- fileinfo is null
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    fileinfo[i] = new FileInfo(files[i]);//Exception at this line of code
//   ^--- fileinfo is still null!
}
```

you are trying to use the indexer on a null reference to set a value.  I think you want:

```
FileInfo[] fileinfo= new FileInfo[num];
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    fileinfo[i] = new FileInfo(files[i]);//Exception at this line of code
}
```

or just

```
FileInfo[] fileinfo = files.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

After reading your comments, it seems that you think that `FileInfo[] fileinfo=null;` will initialize an array of null values (which is true in some languages, but not C#).  In fact, it creates an array variable that is *itself* a null value.  To initialize an array, you use the syntax `FileInfo[] fileinfo=new FileInfo[size];` which *will* create an array of null values (more precisely, of the default value for `FileInfo`, which is `null` since it's a reference type).

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing  `FileInfo[] fileinfo`.

Fix:  `FileInfo[] fileInfo = new FileInfo[num]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems...a little complex...for what it does. Wouldn't it be a lot easier to let the framework do the work for you and say something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> ContentsOfDirectoryTreeRootedAt( string rootDirectory )
{
  DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo( rootDirectory ) ;
  if ( !root.Exists ) throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(rootDirectory) ;

  foreach( FileSystemInfo entry in root.EnumerateFileSystemInfos(null,SearchOption.AllDirectories) )
  {
    yield return entry ;
  }

}
```

Then you can invoke it along these lines:

```
foreach( FileInfo fi in ContentsOfDirectoryTreeRootedAt( @"C:\foo\bar" ).Where( x => x is FileInfo ).Cast<FileInfo>() )
{
  Console.Write( "FileName: {0}" , fi.FullName ) ;
  Console.Write( "\t" );
  Console.Write( "Last Updated: {1}" , fi.LastWriteTime ) ;
  Console.Write( "\t" );
  Console.Write( "Size: {0:0.0}kb" , (decimal)fi.Length / 1024m ) ;
  Console.WriteLine() ;
}
```